# Iwasawa theory over function fields - How do eigenvalues vary in $\mathbb Z_\ell$ towers?

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, l-functions, iwasawa-theory

Consider a tower of curves $\dots \to C_n \to C_{n-1} \dots \to C_1$ over $\mathbb F_q$ where $C_n: f(x^{\ell^n},y) = 0$.We can look at the multiset $S_n$ of eigenvalues of the Frobenius $\sigma_q$ on $H^1(\overline{C_n},\mathbb Z_\ell)$ and also the characteristic polynomial $g_n(x)$.

We will have a factorization $g_n(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x)$ and we can ask how $f_i(x)$ varies with $i$. This could be called a version of Iwasawa theory over function fields, has it been considered in the literature before?

I have found papers that study how the class group/class number changes with $i$ but that's a little less information than the characteristic polynomial itself.

Comment: Do such towers exist?

Comment: Yes, you can consider $f(x^{\ell^n},y) = 0$ for instance

Comment: (I have been thinking about this problem and want to make sure that my results are new.)

Comment: That has Galois group $\mathbb Z_\ell \rtimes \mathbb Z_\ell$, at least if $q$ contains the $\ell$th roots of unity.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain more? You get the automorphisms that send $x \to x\zeta_{\ell^n}$ on $C_n$ but what other automorphisms do you get? Are you including the Frobenius? If so, I guess I meant the *geometric* Galois group should be $\mathbb Z_\ell$ - sorry for being unclear.

Comment: I am not sure what to call this Galois group but maybe let's just restrict to the class of examples I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I'm including the Frobenius. The way that Frobenius acts on the geometric Galois group imposes some strong restrictions about the eigenvalues of Frobenius, just based on the fact that Frobenius and this group both act on cohomology. It's possible that, beyond this, not much is known.